# subvarieties of abelian varieties over number fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

How "special" are closed subvarieties of abelian varieties over number fields? (Dimension 1 is easy.)

For example: Are there interesting families of varieties of general type which are not closed subvarieties of abelian varieties?

This is motivated by Faltings' articles *Diophantine approximation on abelian varieties.* Ann. of Math. (2) 133 (1991), no. 3, 549–576 and *The general case of S. Lang's conjecture.* Barsotti Symposium in Algebraic Geometry (Abano Terme, 1991), 175–182, Perspect. Math., 15, Academic Press, San Diego, CA, 1994.: To which varieties does Faltings' theorem apply?

(There is the related question [Properties of subvarieties of a simple abelian variety](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115191/properties-of-subvarieties-of-a-simple-abelian-variety).)

Comment: What do you mean by "interesting"? Simply connected varieties, for instance hypersurfaces, complete intersections... do not map non-trivially to any abelian variety.

Answer (score 5):

A smooth hypersurface of degree $d\geq 1$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ is simply connected when $n\geq 2$, as abx comments.

More generally, 
a simply connected positive-dimensional smooth projective variety is not a subvariety of an abelian variety. Thus, K3 surfaces are not subvarieties of abelian varieties, and positive-dimensional Fano varieties are not subvarieties   of abelian varieties. With the appropriate definition of "Calabi-Yau", positive-dimensional subvarieties of abelian varieties are not Calabi-Yau.

Basically, subvarieties of abelian varieties are the varieties with a "large" Albanese variety.

Comment: Thanks. Hypersurfaces $X \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}^n_\mathbf{C}$ are simply connected for $n \geq 3$ because this induces an injection on fundamental groups.